# Passing values from view to .js file based on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that gets data from Model and displays the information. I am getting a list of school with school name and school Id from Model and then using foreach loop, I am creating a dynamic table based the number of schools the Model returns.

Below is the code I have for my view.

```
 @if (Model.SelectedSchool != null)
 {
      foreach (var sch in Model.SelectedSchool )
      {
          <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
              <td class="col-sm-9">
                   @sch.SchoolName
              </td>
              <td class="col-sm-3">
                   <button class="btn btn-default" id="recentlySelected" name="btnRecentlySelected" type="button">
                              Select
                   </button>
              </td>
          </tr>                                                
          </table>
       }
  }
```

Here SchoolName is the property in the list I am getting from Model.
SchoolId is also in the list.

Below is the view I get

[image]

Now, I want that when a user clicks Select button, beside each school name, that specific SchoolId, is passed to the .js file where I am handing the javascript functions and based on the schoolId, the javascript function, generates the address of the school.

My question is how can I link the SchoolId's that I am getting in the SelectedSchool list to the respective Select buttons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a js file, add the reference to your view (or worst case, hard-code script inside script tags in view) - Inside bind to the select buttons click event similar to ► `document.getElementById('recentlySelected').addEventListener('click', function(){// your code here to get data from table})` but if you are not familiar with JavaScript at all it might be a good start to look at [**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [**https://api.jquery.com/**](https://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are setting the same id to all the buttons generated from the loop. This is invalid HTML ! **Id values should be unique**. So delete the Id property (unless you absolutely need it for something. in that case you need to make it unique)!

You can keep the school id in html 5 data attribute and read it later in javascript as needed.

Assuming you have a property called `SchoolId`,

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-schoolid="@sch.SchoolId" 
                                                name="btnRecentlySelected" type="button">
                              Select
 </button>
```

*You can have the same attribute value for name property.* You can use this as your jQuery selector when registering the click event on these buttons.

Now some unobutrusive javascript to bind a click event on this button

```
$(function(){

  $("[name='btnRecentlySelected']").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var schoolId= $(this).data("schoolid");
     alert(schoolId);
     // to do : Do something with the schoolId
  });

});
```

Comment: Just to the benefit of OP in case they are new to HTML, Javascript, etc.. while using a class as a selector works, using none class selector to bind your events, such as `data-id="myBtn"`is safer when your UI/CSS team keeps moving classes, which is what they should be allowed to do as styling is separate from functionality, but they won't touch data attributes and ids, etc.. :)

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but that's actually a problem in practice. Ids and classes are *structural*, they are not there for style, or at least exclusively for style. CSS can use them as a selector to apply styles, but an id/class has deeper meaning than that.

Comment: I do not have css class as my jQuery selector in the answer. I am using the name attribute for jQuery selector. name is something programmers should be maintaining, not designers